# Printing a .txt file in a graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I'm working through a program take in a user's .txt file which works with 3 lines at a time: 1st line is X coordinates, 2nd line is y coordinates. 3rd line is the style. (The user can enter as many different sections of 3 lines as they want. The program will run through processing from `lines[0]-line[2]` and printing the corresponding graph, then `lines[3]-line[5]` and do the same. on and on until it reaches the end. 
Example of one graph:

```
2 4 6

1 2 3

--r
```

I have the foundation built. However, when I try to implement the third line into plt.plot() the program crashes because of an unrecognized error:

`'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)`
(Full traceback at bottom)

ValueError: Unrecognized character 
 in format string.
See my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("testfile.txt") as f:
    lines = list(f)
    x_components = list(map(int, lines[0].split()))
    y_components = list(map(int, lines[1].split()))
    style = lines[2]
    line_to_string = "".join(map(str, style))
    plt.plot(x_components, y_components, line_to_string)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plots.py", line 11, in <module>
    plt.plot(x_components, y_components, line_to_string)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2795, in plot
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1666, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 225, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 366, in _plot_args
    linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 106, in _process_plot_format
    'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)
ValueError: Unrecognized character 
 in format string
>
```

The screen capture of the .txt file is below:

[image]

Comment: Including the error would help people trying to help you out a lot!

Comment: Thanks. See edits

Comment: Please post the _full_ traceback

Comment: Actually, your code runs fine for me, but I made sure the input file had no lines in between the data. If it had I got a similar error. Check your input data...

Comment: @daveg have a look at the screenshot. Is your input the same?

Comment: I added an answer - but generally, you need to be sure you have a valid format string, and some characters may be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it from this line  - `style = lines[2]`.
`line_to_string` can contain `'\n'` or something

Answer (score 0):

you should strip newlines from the end of the format string:

```
with open("testfile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x_components = list(map(int, lines[0].split()))
    y_components = list(map(int, lines[1].split()))
    style = lines[2].strip()
    line_to_string = "".join(map(str, style))
    plt.plot(x_components, y_components, line_to_string)
```

BTW, the method is fragile if you don't check that the format string is valid.